# insert the same word under the line and its multiples

Tags: text-processing

text:

```
my1line
my2line
my3line
my4line
my5line
my6line
my7line
my8line
...
```

words that want to be inserted :

```
hello
```

desired output:

```
my1line
my2line
hello
my3line
my4line
hello
my5line
my6line
hello
my7line
my8line
....
```

Tucked in repeatedly every few lines until it runs out, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

```bsh
awk '1; !(NR%2) {print "hello"}' file
```

Print every line. Print "hello" every second line.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'NR%2==0{$0=$0"\nhello"}1' filename
```

output

```
my1line
my2line
hello
my3line
my4line
hello
my5line
my6line
hello
my7line
my8line
hello
```

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed's *n-skip-m* address operator:

```
sed '2~2a hello' textfile
```

Use the `-i` option if you want to edit the file in-place.

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe '$_ .= "hello\n" unless $. % 2' input
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Gnu sed` and its `step operator`. Test with :

```
seq 100 | sed '3~2 s/.*/hello\n&/'
```

Or with standard `sed`. Test with :

```
seq 100 | sed 'n;s/.*/&\nhello/;'
```

Of course use your file as input. So the preceding example become:

```
sed 'n;s/.*/&\nhello/;' datafile
```